# Drupal View (Page) vs Taxonomy

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have the following problem:

I use taxonomys (tx) as tags. They can be added when the node is created. So I don't know how many tx I have or what ID they have.
The path of the tx is like the following:

/foo/element1
/foo/element2
/foo/element3
...

The secound element is the tx.

Now I want to use a view (page) to handle the tx-path:
/foo/%

The problem is, when I open a path like the one on top I see the theme of the node-taxonomy.tpl.php but not the style I set in the view.

Whenever I open a path in the form (/foo/not-a-tx) I can see the output of the view.

Could someone give me a hint how to get out the view output but not the tx-output?

Thanks 
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this way:

- I use a view block (not a page)
- I added a new output area in my ,info file
- I use [this way](http://adaptivethemes.com/page-template-suggestions-for-taxonomy-vocabs) to show only the vocab
- I show the block in the new area online bei foo/*

It works Okay for me.
Thx to every one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get rid of the taxonomy pages completely?

If so, you can use a hook_menu_alter() and unset the taxonomy page.

EX.

```
hook_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']);
}
```

You'd have to look at the $items array to pinpoint the name of the registered menu path, but I think this is it.

This will remove the taxonomy page for all vocabularies however.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But this is not the answer. I don't want to remove all taxonomys.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to make a view to override the *internal* drupal path of the taxonomy term page: taxonomy/term/% (where % is the taxonomy id) and **not** the aliased path, which in your case is foo/%

[**Optional but saves work:** There is already an example view that is bundled with Drupal that implements the taxonomy view. Go to Views > List and you will see the the view is greyed out and it is called

`Default Node view: taxonomy_term  (default)`

All you need to do is enable it and modify it to your needs]

Don't worry about the aliases. You can define your URL pattern at `/admin/build/path/pathauto` (make sure pathauto module is enabled. You can download it at http://drupal.org/project/pathauto ). In your case the pattern would be `foo/[cat]` where `[cat]` is a token for category. Make sure you enter this pattern under `Taxonomy Term paths` in the pathauto automated alias settings.

Comment: Thank you but with this way I override ALL taxonomy. But I need it only for one. But I solved the Problem with a little work around.